# Using javascript navigate to a page and also send querystring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, query-string

I want to navigate from page1.html to page2.html and at the same time adding querystring in URL using javascript.

I tried:

```
window.location.href = 'page2.html?uname=mustafa';
```

It does navigate to page2.html but "?uname=mustafa" is not added in URL.
So am unable to parse querystring on page2. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Basically, I want to send data between html pages without using server-side scripting.

Comment: I just tried your code on a chrome console and it did what you are asking for

Comment: how about using sessionStorage?

Comment: what is your serverside set up? maybe you are using a cms or some sytem thats stripping the query string?

Comment: means you are also able to see full string in your URL, correct? And yeah I want to extract data from url in my project so I want to use this approach.

Comment: Am using PHP to get data(username) from mysql and pass it to page1(login) and open page2, welcoming 'username. and since am building mobileapp (phonegap) I cant use php at client side.

Comment: try `window.location = 'page2.html?uname=mustafa';`

Comment: It turns out there is some error in other part of code. Above solution worked!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using just

```
window.location = 'page2.html?uname=mustafa';
```

instead of using `.href`? This should preserve the querystring.

Worked for me in Chrome and FF with `.href` just fine, but I used absolute URLs:

```
window.location = 'http://google.com/?test=blah&foo=bar';
window.location.href = 'http://google.com/?test=blah&foo=bar';
```

Comment: still not preserving :(

Comment: It turns out there is some error in other part of code. Above solution worked!

Comment: don't forget to mark the accepted answer, or create an answer for any solution you figured out yourself

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into this problem before as well. I used `location.href` with an absolute URL and a parameters array like the follow:

```
var params = [];
params.push("uname=" +mustafa);
location.href = "http://localhost:port/page2.html?" + params.join("&");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.location = `addUser.html?userId=${userId}`;
```

here `userId` is a parameter and `${userId}` is variable value